# Python make math calculations faster

Tags: python, math

I have this code to find the Pythagorean triplets, which works fine.
I just want to make it faster. On my Intel i5 1135G7, it takes about 0.1272754669189453 time. Maybe it could be done using the `multiprocessing` module, as my CPU is not 100% utilized.

```
import math
import time 


results = [] 

start_time = time.time()

def triplets4(n):
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(a, n):
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) 
            if c.is_integer() and c<=n:
                results.append([a , b, int(c)])

triplets4(1000)

end_time = time.time()

for x in results:
    print(x)

print(end_time-start_time) #print time elapsed
```

Comment: this is basic math, you could get orders of magnitude faster by compiling it to something statically typed, using [cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/) or [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: Hit up your search engine for a better algorithm, you might even find one on this site.

Comment: [Similar goal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/282688/29485).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python programmer but after observing a few opportunities, I thought I'd make a few modifications for performance optimisation. Python is not a great language to use for speed except when using optimised library functions. You need a script you can compile for performance. Multi-threading can make your program faster but often requires a major refactoring of code. I excluded a=0 from the outputs as I don't think they count as triples. Anywho, this is what I did which runs all of 20%(!) faster on my computer, even after removing a=0 from your script. While the performance gain isn't great, I think some lessons can be learnt from the changes I made.

```
import math
import time 


results = [] 

start_time = time.time()

def triplets4(n):
    n2 = n*n
    for a in range(1, n):
        a2 = a*a
        blim = 1+int(math.sqrt(n2 - a2))
        for b in range(a+1, blim):
            arg = a2 + b * b
            c = math.sqrt(arg) 
            if c.is_integer():
                results.append([a , b, int(c)])

triplets4(1000)

end_time = time.time()

for x in results:
    print(x)

print(end_time-start_time) #print time elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

One simple way is to add a check for `(a * b) % 12 != 0` before running `sqrt` or `is_integer`.

According to the [Wolfram page on Pythagorean Triplets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html), the product of the legs (`a` and `b`) of a Pythagorean triplet/triangle is always divisible by 12.

### Long Answer

We should profile your code first. Just to keep things simple, I've removed the print statements and timers, so we're working with this version of your code:

```py
import math

results = [] 

def triplets4(n):
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(a, n):
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) 
            if c.is_integer() and c<=n:
                results.append([a , b, int(c)])

triplets4(1000)
```

Using cProfile:

```bash
python -m cProfile .\pythagorean.py      
         1002950 function calls in 0.270 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.270    0.270 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.270    0.270 pythagorean.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.175    0.175    0.269    0.269 pythagorean.py:5(triplets4)
   500500    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 {built-in method math.sqrt}
   500500    0.043    0.000    0.043    0.000 {method 'is_integer' of 'float' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1167(_find_and_load)
     1881    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

Most of the time is spent on `math.sqrt` and `is_integer`.

So, to speed up your code we should just make fewer calls to those functions.

The simplest way I can think of is a divisibility test.

```py
import math

results = [] 

def triplets4(n):
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(a, n):
            # product of legs must be divisible by 12
            if (a * b) % 12 != 0: continue
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) 
            if c.is_integer() and c<=n:
                results.append([a , b, int(c)])

triplets4(1000)
```

```bash
python -m cProfile .\pythagorean_v2.py
         280672 function calls in 0.174 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.174    0.174 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.174    0.174 pythagorean_v2.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.135    0.135    0.174    0.174 pythagorean_v2.py:5(triplets4)
   139361    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {built-in method math.sqrt}
   139361    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 {method 'is_integer' of 'float' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1167(_find_and_load)
     1881    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

In both versions we're still appending the same amount of triplets (1881), so that's a good sign.